# What notation do we use to refer explicitly to the set of cosets/equivalence classes?

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation

I was preparing my notes on the First Isomorphism Theorem and tried to say in formal notation

> The number of cosets of a group $G$ with respect to the kernel of $\phi$ is precisely the number of elements in the codomain $G'$.

I am aware that we use $|G|$ to denote the number of elements in $G$. But I'm not too sure what we use to denote the number of *cosets*.

My guess would be $\left | G/\ker(\phi) \right | = |G'|$, as the elements of the quotient group are the cosets in themselves.

Is this correct, or is there more standard notation for this?

Or am I perhaps misunderstanding it all?

Comment: I think the $|G'|$ notation is perfectly acceptable and also widely used

Comment: Thank you. But my focus was rather on the number of cosets that a group has when quotiented out by some other group.

Comment: you mean $|G/\ker \phi|$? That is correct and acceptable too

Comment: Instead of *codomain* $G'$, you need *image* of $\phi$, unless of course $\phi$ is surjective.

Comment: The title does not reflect the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A standard notation for the number of cosets is the [index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_of_a_subgroup): $[G:\ker(\phi)]$.

The advantage of this notation is that it is defined for all subgroups, not just normal subgroups. So, it makes sense to talk about the index $[G:H]$ even when it does not make sense to talk about the quotient group $G/H$.

Comment: I think a lot of people use the notation G/H for the collection of cosets even when H is not normal.